# Different Output of TCPDF in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a question for you. I've created a TCPDF using php, when I printed out the output using my Chrome browser and it works great, but when I printed it out using Firefox some of the words came out at the top of the page. Is there a possible way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: show us the code with the error

Comment: What does Adobe Reader make of it? This sounds like a possible problem with PDF.js that Firefox uses to render PDF documents.

Comment: @k102 - there is no error on the output, it's just misplaced some words

Comment: @MikeW - Actually I've installed a pdf plug in for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I've Solved the Problem. It's a browser issue 
M.Eskandari is correct. I've re-installed my Firefox and it works great thank you to those people who responded to my query.